# How can I check if a cursor is locked to a window?

Tags: autohotkey

I need to be able to check if a cursor is locked to a window or not. There is a program called ScummVM (to emulate old games), and a keyboard shortcut (ctrl+m) will lock the cursor to the game window. I need to be able to check whether or not the cursor is locked to the window -- not just if it's hovering over the window. How can I do this?

For example:

```
if CursorLocked("ahk_exe scummvm.exe")
{
    do this
    and this
    etc
}
```

Comment: A hacky method could be to use MouseMove to try moving the mouse outside the window then checking the coordinates